# Python: Adding another value to an existing key dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to take in all the files at a given path, and order them based on my data title names.
So my data title names are:

```
data_titles = ['CPU','Physical_Disk','Memory','Network']
```

The files at this given path are named like `'CPU_data.txt'` and `'Memory_data.txt'` but there are also some that have more than one file per data title for example `'Physical_Disk_data_1.txt'` and `'Physical_Disk_data_2.txt'.`

I am trying to create a dicitonary in the style of:

```
{'Network': 'Network_data.txt', 
 'Physical_Disk': ['Physical_Disk_data_1.txt','Physical_Disk_data_2.txt'], 
 'CPU': 'CPU_data.txt', 
 'Memory': 'Memory_data.txt'}
```

i.e not overwriting older values

However I keep getting the error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'update'`, if I use append instead of update I get a similar error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`

```
table_csv_files={}
    for file_names in os.listdir(Data_folder):
        for name in data_titles:
            if name in file_names:
                if name in table_csv_files:
                    table_csv_files[name].update(file_names)
                    # Have also tried table_csv_files.append({name:file_names})
                else:
                    table_csv_files[name]=file_names

                print table_csv_files
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you set a proper alignment for your code? It does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your values are sometimes strings (e.g. for `Network`) and sometimes lists (e.g. for `Physical_Disk`). If you make sure that they are always lists you can easily append to them:

```
data_titles = ['CPU','Physical_Disk','Memory','Network']
table_csv_files={}
listdir_output = ['Network_data.txt', 'Physical_Disk_data_1.txt','Physical_Disk_data_2.txt', 'CPU_data.txt', 'Memory_data.txt']
for file_names in listdir_output:
    for name in data_titles:
        if name in file_names:
            if name in table_csv_files:
                table_csv_files[name].append(file_names)
            else:
                table_csv_files[name] = [file_names]
print table_csv_files
```

Output:

```
{'Memory': ['Memory_data.txt'], 'Physical_Disk': ['Physical_Disk_data_1.txt', 'Physical_Disk_data_2.txt'], 'Network': ['Network_data.txt'], 'CPU': ['CPU_data.txt']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `defaultdict` whose default value is an empty `list`, then you can `append` to the dictionary values without worrying about which keys already exist in your dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

table_csv_files = defaultdict(list)

for file_names in os.listdir(Data_folder):
     for name in data_titles:
          if name in file_names:
                table_csv_files[name].append(file_names)

print table_csv_files 
# {'CPU': ['CPU_data.txt'], 'Memory': ['Memory_data_1.txt', 'Memory_data_2.txt'], 'Physical_Disk': ['Physical_Disk_data.txt'], 'Network': ['Network_data.txt']}
```

Comment: I didn't know, and according to the documentation is better than using setdefault [python3.5 docs] (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: @terencehill Yes. Thanks for stating that.

Answer (score 0):

**According to Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict]) it's better to use defaultdict(), see the answer by *Moses Koledoye***

You cannot append to a dictionary. You can append to a value corresponding to a **key** if that **value** is a *list* (or antoher object that implement the append method).

I think this is the best way to make the code easy to follow. The function **setdefault** add a new *list* only if the **key** is not present.

```
   if name in file_names:
        table_csv_files.setdefault(name, [])
        table_csv_files[name].append(file_names)
```

Answer (score -1):

## Dictionary[key] = new value

here is a simple example of how you can add/update another value to an existing key in dictionary.

```
my_dict = {'name': 'Rajiv Sharma', 'city': 'Delhi'}
print my_dict
my_dict['city'] = 'Kuala Lumpur'
print my_dict
```

output:

```
{'city': 'Delhi', 'name': 'Rajiv Sharma'}
{'city': 'Kuala Lumpur', 'name': 'Rajiv Sharma'}
```